# Bayesian Structural Time Series in BSTS package: implementing mixed model

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian, mixed-model, causalimpact

I have been using *BSTS* package for quite a while and I have found it pretty effective with respect to *ARIMAX* models.

I was wondering whether it would be possible to share regression coefficients in the regression part (the equation being: $Y_t = \mu_t + \mathbf{x_t} \boldsymbol{\beta} + S_t + \epsilon_t$, with $\mu_t$ being the level at time $t$, $S_t$ being the seasonal component at time $t$) across different time series.

Furthermore I would like to have also mixed effects so that my new equation would become something like:

$Y_{it} = \mu_t + \mathbf{x_t} \boldsymbol{\beta} + \mathbf{Z_t} \boldsymbol{\eta_i}+ S_t + \epsilon_t$.

Question: **Is this achievable through BSTS?**

Having read Steven Scott presentation I see he implemented Lasso Variable selection and other stuff which makes it difficult for me to implement it directly in STAN..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like version 0.7.0 added support for this model.

> As of version 0.7.0, bsts supports having multiple observations at the same time point. In this case the basic model is taken to be
>
> $y_{t, j} = Z^T\alpha_t + \beta^Tx_{t, j} + \epsilon_{t, j}$
>
> This is a regression model where all observations with the same time point share a common time series effect.

Comment: Thank you for the help ! 

Unfortunately I see no reference to mixed effects